# Identifying candidate distributions with a desired set of qualitative characteristics

Tags: distributions, moments, fat-tails

Is there a good way of finding candidate distributions based on a set of qualitative characteristics?  For instance, at the moment I am looking for a continuous univariate two-parameter distribution, bounded by zero on the left (i.e. with a scale and a shape parameter), with a single internal mode, for which the second moment fails to exist due to a fat tail for some but not all values of the parameters. (This is intended as a model of trading volume for certain securities).)

I could go through Johnson, Kotz and Balakrishnan in all of its 1500+ page glory, but it seems like there should be a less tedious way of finding a distribution with specified characteristics.

Identifying candidate distributions with a desired set of qualitative characteristics

Comment: Potentially a bit off topic but I used to approach similar problems by calculating MLEs of distribution parameters for several distributions then graphically plotting them to see which best fit my data. Admittedly this doesn't satisfy your "characteristic" requirement but could be a useful method of distribution identification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no general way to identify distributions that satisfy some arbitrary list of characteristics. If you restrict the possible characteristics to a small set then you could perhaps set up a database of commonly used distributions for which those characteristics are known, but outside something like that, no.

As for your specific request, perhaps the scale-location family of the [Fréchet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distribution) with the location parameter set to 0. That is, with density

$$f(x) = {\frac  {\alpha }{\sigma}}\;\left({\frac  {x}{\sigma}}\right)^{{-1-\alpha }}\;e^{{-({\frac  {x}{\sigma}})^{{-\alpha }}}}\, x>0,\,\alpha>0,\,\sigma>0$$

The variance is finite for $\alpha>2$. The mode is $\sigma\left({\frac  {\alpha }{\alpha +1}}\right)^{{\frac  {1}{\alpha }}}$

Comment: Yes, interesting. The question I was trying to answer was how to tell if an unusually high volume spike is to a specified degree unlikely given recent history. It had not occurred to me that the question so structured was an extreme value problem, but of course it is. Thanks!